# Passing variables to aws cli command in bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cli

I'm new to writing bash scripts and am having trouble with passing in variable to an AWS CLI command. I'm sure there's an easy fix for this, and I'm just having trouble understanding this syntax. Below is the script I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG_RECORDER=`aws configservice describe-configuration-recorders
export CONFIG_RECORDER_NAME=$(jq -r '.ConfigurationRecorders[].name' <<<"$CONFIG_RECORDER")

sudo yum -y install jq

aws configservice delete-configuration-recorder --configuration-recorder-name $CONFIG_RECORDER_NAME
```

The purpose of this script is to delete the configuration recorder using the aws cli command. I'm getting an error that `aws: error: argument --configuration-recorder-name: expected one argument`

I have a variable, `$CONFIG_RECORDER_NAME`, being specified as the argument but for some reason it is not reading. Any advice on how to pass in this variable to this command would be helpful.

Comment: If you echo $CONFIG_RECORDER_NAME, is it correct? PS if you run `aws --debug configservice ...` then it will print out the set of command line args that were passed to awscli.

Comment: Yes, the value is correct. When using --debug, it still just tells me "expected one argument"

Comment: That doesn't sound right. You will see a debug line such as `DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['--debug', 'configservice', 'delete-configuration-recorder', '--configuration-recorder-name', 'fred'` if you provided an argument of `fred` for `--configuration-recorder-name`. The symptoms you share suggest that you provided no argument for that option.

Comment: BTW there's a typo on the `CONFIG_RECORDER=` line in your script. Missing close quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work correctly if the `aws configservice describe-configuration-recorders` invocation returns a single configuration recorder name:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo yum -y install jq

CONFIG_RECORDER=`aws configservice describe-configuration-recorders`
# echo "CONFIG_RECORDER="$CONFIG_RECORDER

CONFIG_RECORDER_NAME=$(jq -r '.ConfigurationRecorders[].name' <<<"$CONFIG_RECORDER")
# echo "CONFIG_RECORDER_NAME="$CONFIG_RECORDER_NAME

aws configservice \
    delete-configuration-recorder \
    --configuration-recorder-name $CONFIG_RECORDER_NAME
```

There's actually no need to use `jq`. You could simply use:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG_RECORDER_NAME=`aws configservice describe-configuration-recorders --query 'ConfigurationRecorders[0].name' --output text`

aws configservice \
    delete-configuration-recorder \
    --configuration-recorder-name $CONFIG_RECORDER_NAME
```